# why my array won't back to 0 (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

```js
var a = ["red", "blue", "green"];
var i = 0
$(".button").click(function() {
  i++;
  if (i >= 3) {
    i = 0;
  }
  console.log(i);
  $("body").addClass(a[i]);
  console.log(a[i]);
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="button">Click</button>
```

It can turn from white to blue and green, but if i click the button again it won't turn to red, blue, and green. But the console show 1,2,0,1,2,0 and also the color blue, green, red, blue

Comment: You never remove any class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not ever *removing* the old class, so eventually the body has all three classes and it just uses the last one. Add

```
$("body").removeClass(a[i]);
```

to the beginning of your click handler:

```js
var a = ["red", "blue", "green"];
var i = 0
$(".button").click(function() {
  $("body").removeClass(a[i]);
  i++;
  if (i >= 3) {
    i = 0;
  }
  console.log(i);
  $("body").addClass(a[i]);
  console.log(a[i]);
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button type="button" class="button">Click</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will add and remove the different colour classes to and from the document and will not affect any other document classes that might have been assigned before.

```js
const a = ["red", "blue", "green"];
a.i=-1;a.col=function(){const cl=document.body.classList;
 cl.remove(this[this.i++]);
 cl.add(this[this.i%=3]);
 console.log(this.i,this[this.i]);
};

document.querySelector(".button").onclick=ev=>a.col();
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `$("body").addClass(a[i]);` to `document.body.className = a[i];`

And you don't need jQuery.

Like so:

```js
var a = ["red", "blue", "green"];
var i = 0
document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  i++;
  if (i >= 3) {
    i = 0;
  }
  console.log(i);
  document.body.className = a[i];
  console.log(a[i]);
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: Won't this remove any other classes already added?

Comment: @phuzi Yes, but the OP didn't say they needed that.